# Controller method parameter value is null upon postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Here is what i am trying to do:

```
public ActionResult GetByConfirmationNumber(string confirmationNumber) {
if (confirmationNumber == null) return View();
            CPRSearchManager searchManager = new CPRSearchManager();
            IncidentLite[] cprData = searchManager.GetDataByConfirmationNumber(confirmationNumber, CurrentUser.Name);
            var cprSearchModel = new CPRSearchModel {
                IncidentsArray = cprData
            };
            return View(cprSearchModel); }
```

Basically, when initially navigated to this method, confirmatioNumber is null. What i want to do is change the value of confirmationNumber upon an Ajax request and then return a view with the model. Here's my ajax code

```
function getCPRData() {
        var confirmationNumberValue = $("#confirmation_number_textBox").val();
        alert(confirmationNumberValue);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("GetByConfirmationNumber", "CPRSearch")',
            data: { confirmationNumber : confirmationNumberValue },
            success: function() {
                alert(confirmationNumberValue);
            }
        });
    }
```

I verified to make sure confirmationNumberValue is not null via the alert. But upon this ajax request, confirmationNumber in the action is still null. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: That's not a postback, that's an AJAX request, don't mix them up

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto my apologies, i will edit that straight away.

Comment: Just copied and pasted your code and it worked fine for me!

Comment: @Shyju do you mean that upon the Ajax request, your confirmation number updates with the value?

Comment: I got the value in `confirmationNumber` parameter of the action method. I did not get `NULL` as you mentioned

Comment: @Shyju that's interesting, could you please tell me what you entered as your value for confirmationNumberValue?

Comment: Compare with this working fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/HZ4JrX

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163430/discussion-between-spartan-117-and-shyju).

Comment: @Shyju i just noticed yours is a bit different. I am calling back to the same action from the view that renders the view in the first place. Your's calls a different method.

Comment: Split your single GET/POST to separate GET and separate POST methods.  in your POST i'd redirect to a "details" view.  you could do this partial views so that your are only updating part of your page.

Answer (score 0):

To read a string from the request body add the FromBody attribute to the parameter:

```
public ActionResult GetByConfirmationNumber([FromBody]string confirmationNumber)
```